# Webmoney Privat24 Android

Tags: android-sdk, android

Желаю всем здравствовать! Кто-нибудь знает как включить платежи(Приват, вэбмоней) в свое андроид приложение? Есть какое-то АПИ? и есть ли какие-то примеры? че-то в гугле как-то пусто.

Comment: Вам конкретно приват/вебмани или платежи вообще?

Comment: надо именно приват и вэбмани

Answer (score 2):

С webmany все более-менее понятно - там есть [официальный api](https://api4mini.webmoney.ru/). Но у webmany сейчас небольшие проблемы с блокированием счетов в Украине.
C Приватом тоже - [ссылка на апи](https://api.privatbank.ua/).

Но есть другая проблема - Ваше приложение могут не пустить в googlePlay. Если за эти деньги Вы покупаете пиццу или оплачиваете такси - нет проблем. Если покупаете виртуальные плюшки внутри приложения - тогда лучше [In-App Purchase](http://habrahabr.ru/post/123642/).

Comment: а можно подключить и то и другое одновременно? В Украине большинство знают что такое In-App Purchase и как через него оплачивать?  насколько я понял in-app purchase будет хавать 30% дохода. Если посмотреть по рынку, то большинство в Украине могут оплатить либо через смс, либо через приват и вэбмани

Comment: а кто мешает? Главное что бы Гугл был не против.

>  Если посмотреть по рынку, то большинство в Украине могут оплатить либо через смс, либо через приват и вэбмани

Из моих знакомых никто не оплачивает через вебмани, приват также не сильно жалуют (я несколько раз оплачивал приватом... мне хватило этого приключения - кредиткой другого банка оплатить нереально, приходиться идти в банк и платить наличкой. Кредитки привата у меня нет). А вот In-App Purchase - так это все. Но может быть у меня выборка нестандартная.

Comment: in-app purchase каким образом работает? нужно заводить специально гугль кошелек или можно оплатить с помощью денег на карточке твоего мобильного?

Comment: украину я не видел в списке стран которые могут оплачивать in-app через мобильного оператора

Comment: да, Украины пока нет. Но можно через кредитку, привязанную к google wallet. Насколько мне известно, пока только в Испании тестируют оплату через оператора. В Украине вроде Киевстар пробовал такое дело внедрить, но не знаю о результатах.